# Ant property bug

Tags: ant

I have two deployment configurations.
Each configuration store in its property file.
Dev configuration in dev.properties:

```
deploy.wowza.domain=DEV_IP_ADDRESS
```

Prod configuration in prod.properties:

```
deploy.wowza.domain=PROD_IP_ADDRESS
```

I have build.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project name="MAIN" default="dev" basedir=".">    
<target name="dev">
        <property file="${java.root.dir}/ant/dev.properties"/>

        <echo>
            DEV
            ${deploy.wowza.domain}
        </echo>
        <sleep seconds="1"/>

    </target>

    <target name="prod">
        <property file="${java.root.dir}/ant/prod.properties"/>

        <echo>
            PROD
            ${deploy.wowza.domain}
        </echo>

        <antcall target="deploy"/>

    </target>
</project>
```

If I run prod or dev task it show correct property value only from second run

```
D:\Dropbox\camwithme>ant prod
Buildfile: D:\Dropbox\camwithme\build.xml

prod:
     [copy] Copying 1 file to D:\Dropbox\camwithme\wowza_cam\ant
     [echo]
     [echo]             PROD
     [echo]             PROD_IP_ADDRESS
     [echo]

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 0 seconds

D:\Dropbox\camwithme>ant dev
Buildfile: D:\Dropbox\camwithme\build.xml

dev:
     [copy] Copying 1 file to D:\Dropbox\camwithme\wowza_cam\ant
     [echo]
     [echo]             DEV
     [echo]             PROD_IP_ADDRESS     !!! Should be dev ip here !!!
     [echo]

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 0 seconds

D:\Dropbox\camwithme>ant prod
Buildfile: D:\Dropbox\camwithme\build.xml

prod:
     [copy] Copying 1 file to D:\Dropbox\camwithme\wowza_cam\ant
     [echo]
     [echo]             PROD
     [echo]             DEV_IP_ADDRESS
     [echo]
```

Comment: Does running ant with the `-verbose` switch reveal anything?

Comment: Yes. It says Override ignored for property "deploy.wowza.domain" How to force override?

Comment: Once an ant property is defined, it can't take another value. Are you defining the `deploy.wowza.domain` property before loading the autogenerated.properties file? If so... don't.

Answer (score 1):

Problem was because of  another build.xml which load properties files before copy